# React Native app crash : Looks like you have configured linking in multiple places

Tags: android, react-native, deep-linking

native app has a crash error in Firebase. I only use it on `useLinking`. Please if you know what the problem is ,I would be very grateful for any advice

```
Fatal Exception: com.facebook.react.common.JavascriptException: Error: Looks like you have configured linking in multiple places. This is likely an error since deep links should only be handled in one place to avoid conflicts. Make sure that:
- You are not using both 'linking' prop and 'useLinking'
- You don't have 'useLinking' in multiple components
- You have set 'android:launchMode=singleTask' in the '<activity />' section of the 'AndroidManifest.xml' file to avoid launching multiple instances

This error is located at:
    in NavigationContainer
    in RCTView
    in Unknown
    in SafeAreaView
    in Unknown
    in Connect(Component)
    in PersistGate
    in Provider
    in Unknown
    in RootApp
    in CodePushComponent
    in RCTView
    in Unknown
    in RCTView
    in Unknown
    in AppContainer, js engine: hermes, stack:
anonymous@1:1161969
flushPassiveEffectsImpl@1:178330
anonymous@1:296362
runWithPriority@1:141995
flushPassiveEffects@1:177886
performSyncWorkOnRoot@1:172359
anonymous@1:142410
anonymous@1:296362
runWithPriority@1:141995
flushSyncCallbackQueueImpl@1:142228
flushSyncCallbackQueue@1:142122
scheduleUpdateOnFiber@1:170233
updateContainer@1:181576
unmountComponentAtNode@1:181798
anonymous@1:191286
unmountApplicationComponentAtRootTag@1:502549
__callFunction@1:118825
anonymous@1:117312
__guard@1:118270
callFunctionReturnFlushedQueue@1:117270

at com.facebook.react.modules.core.ExceptionsManagerModule.reportException(ExceptionsManagerModule.java:83)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
       at com.facebook.react.bridge.JavaMethodWrapper.invoke(JavaMethodWrapper.java:372)
       at com.facebook.react.bridge.JavaModuleWrapper.invoke(JavaModuleWrapper.java:151)
       at com.facebook.react.bridge.queue.NativeRunnable.run(NativeRunnable.java)
       at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:938)
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
       at com.facebook.react.bridge.queue.MessageQueueThreadHandler.dispatchMessage(MessageQueueThreadHandler.java:27)
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223)
       at com.facebook.react.bridge.queue.MessageQueueThreadImpl$4.run(MessageQueueThreadImpl.java:226)
       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:923)

______________
```

```js
----------


// src/navigation/linking.ts

const getLinking = (isLoggedIn: boolean) => {
    const linking: LinkingOptions = {
        prefixes: [
            'https://example.com',
            'http://example.com',
            'example://'
        ],
        config: {
            screens: {
                FAQ: {
                    path: ':lang/page/faq',
                    exact: true
                }
            }
        },
    }
    return linking;
}

// App.tsx

const linking = useMemo(() => {
    return getLinking(isLoggedIn)
}, [isLoggedIn])



return (
    <NavigationContainer linking={linking}>
        <RootStackNavigator />
    </NavigationContainer>
)
```

Comment: can you show us your code in file that contain `NavigationContainer`

Comment: I am using a library, but here is link on it 

https://github.com/react-navigation/react-navigation/blob/main/packages/native/src/NavigationContainer.tsx

Comment: Sorry misunderstood , i have added my NavigationContainer under error , so now you can check it

Comment: ok, i'll check it out

Comment: do you use `useLinking` somewhere in your code?

Comment: No , only linking

Comment: Have u fixed it @UnySonic?

Comment: how to fix this issue? @UnySonic